# What is the best way to isolate these local areas by intensity?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

The general task is to binarize the image so that only the brightest spots remain. But adaptive binarization and the Otsu method do not give an acceptable result due to light traces (shown in the image).[image]

I think that you need to go through the entire image with a small window that will highlight a local minimum in the area.I am counting on the fact that with the correct selection of the threshold, only light spots will remain that need to be found. It should be. [image]But I do not know how to apply the standard opencv threshold function in sliding windows.
UPD:After the proposed adaptive threshold, the image looks like this. Not perfect, but much closer to what I need.It seems that a combination of threshold functions does not always give a better result than a single one.[image]

Comment: Please try to improve your question and give a better idea of what you want to achieve ands what you have tried. Sample input and corresponding expected output images are always appreciated.

Comment: Please also provide your actual input image rather than a screengrab of it combined with other images.

Comment: I removed the excess, but left the image after the thresholding, otherwise it will be difficult to understand what effect I am achieving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the command:

```
outputimg = cv.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv.THRESH_BINARY,11,0)
```

further explanation and examples: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html

Comment: Thank you. With an adaptive threshold, it comes out much better, but still a bunch of extra points remain. I think we need to continue to move in this direction.

Comment: @Maker Do you see that 0 at the end of the command? make a slight change to that (put it -10 for example)

Comment: Yes, that helps. Apparently I did not fully understand the meaning of constants. Already at -3, most of the maxima disappear, but exactly at -1 the picture is very good.